# ruby код как ссылка в link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link, erb

Каким образом я могу преобразовать руби код и link_to,чтобы link_to уводил на страницу пользователя,при клике на имя\фамилию,К примеру имя и фамилия пользователя `<%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %>`

Comment: Задача неясна, сможете расписать подробнее? Что хотели бы получить в итоге - как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: так же как в соц.сети вконтакте.Вы при нажатии на имя своего друга можете попасть на его страничку,т.е его имя + фамилия являются ссылками на его же страницу

Comment: При упоминании имени друга в комментарии или посте? Вида *username или @username?

Comment: теперь не понял Вас я. у Вас есть список друзей на странице "мои друзья". На этой странице опр кол-во друзей,и их имя,при нажатии,ведет на их страницу

Comment: А, так это решается легко: `<%= link_to "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}", user %>`

Comment: Благодарю вас! сейчас проверить нет возможности,позже поставлю как решенное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пользователи объявлены у вас файле config/routes.rb через ресурс

```
resources  :users
```

В представлениях вам будет доступен хелпер `user_path`, который можно задействовать для формирования ссылки на пользователя, либо так

```
<%= link_to "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}", user_path(user) %>
```

либо так

```
<%= link_to user_path(user) do %>
  <%= "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как было сказано ранее, `link_to` умеет принимать блок в качестве параметра. Его стоит использовать в том случае, если, например, потребуется имя и фамилию обернуть в разные `html`-контейнеры.
Если просто нужно вывести строкой - лучше добавить метод пользователю:

## Модель:

```
# ...
def full_name
  "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
end
```

## Представление:

```
<%= link_to user.full_name, ... %>
```

Такой подход более правилен с точки зрения ООП. (См.: [Tell, Don't Ask](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask))